# Connection between devices cannot be established in WiFiDirect

Tags: android, connection, wifi-direct

I try to connect two devices via WiFiDirect. Let's say device-A & B and I use WiFiDirect Demo provided by Android as my code. When I send connection invitation from A->B, connection simply cannot be established. In A's screen it says "Connecting to 'B's device address'". Meanwhile, in B's screen the status of B seems to be "connected"; whereas A's status is still "Available". The interesting part is that sometimes the devices just connect as I want them to do, but sometimes this weird situation occurs. I didn't understand what is going on? This was not the case before. I modified the code according to my needs but that I didn't even touch that connection part. Has this happened to anyone in here before? What might be the problem in here? Please help, I'm simply going crazy!

Comment: Wi-Fi Direct on Android has a lot of issues. I have noticed that connections can be inconsistent, especially between different phone models. Here are a couple good blog posts that talk about some of the issues.

http://thaliproject.org/androidWirelessIssues/
https://sphen.proxmobil.com/android-wi-fi-direct-service-discovery/